# How can I extract a part of a vector to another vector (including positions)

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector with different values (positive and negative), so, I want to select only the 10 lowest odd number values, and the 10 lowest pair values. Help me, please!

Comment: what do you mean "impar" and "par" values?

Comment: I think that she wants to say "odd" and "even". Because that's the meaning in spanish.

Comment: Yes, I have a mistake when I posted! I already corrected. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it using base R.

**vector with odd and even numbers**

```
x <- sample(-100:100, 30)
```

The modulus operator in R help to get the job done. You can use it this way

```
c(
# Extract the lowest even numbers
  head(sort(x[x %% 2 == 0]), 5),
# Extract the lowest odds numbers
  head(sort(x[x %% 2 == 1]), 5)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Given vector `v`as your input vector, you can obtain the desired output (including positions) via the following code

```
names(v) <- seq_along(v)
# lowest 10 odd numbers
low_odd <- sort(v[v%%2==1])[1:10]
# positions of those odd numbers in v
low_odd_pos <- as.numeric(names(low_odd))

# lowest 10 even numbers
low_even <- sort(v[v%%2==0])[1:10]
# positions of those even numbers in v
low_even_pos <- as.numeric(names(low_even))
```

**Example**

```
set.seed(1)
v <- sample(-50:50)
```

then

```
> low_odd
 43 101  39  95  85  72   7  73  45  29 
-49 -47 -45 -43 -41 -39 -37 -35 -33 -31 

> low_odd_pos
 [1]  43 101  39  95  85  72   7  73  45  29
```